# Suggestions for developing WebInterface (using Tomcat)?

Tags: html, tomcat, arm

I am working with TS-7500 (ARM 9) board running Debian Linux (*Linux ts7500 2.6.24.4*). It is connected to a couple of sensors and is running driver code to talk to these sensors.

Every time the C program starts, it reads a couple of *config-parameters* from a *config-file* and starts sensors with those values.

So the task at hand is : presenting a web interface to show/edit these *config-parameters* to user. The task of the web interface can be summarized in four steps :

1. Read *config-parameters* from the *config-file* and show the current configuration
2. Allow user to change the configuration
3. Capture and save the changes to same *config-file*

These *config-parameters* could be presented as drop-down menu items or radio-buttons. And I have a linux background script which restarts the C prg when *config-file* is modified.

I know TS-7500 runs Tomcat. Now please suggest a good way to handle this problem. I have heard about using Servlet and JSPs (am not very familiar with those actually). Which one of them is suitable to generate HTML pages dynamically ? (as I see everytime I need to generate a new HTML page by selecting the current configuration while displaying the page).

Sorry for being very elaborate !

EDIT : Beeps ! No reply ? Come on guyz, is the question not clear ? Or no one has ever faced a similar problem (design problem) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to use a PHP in addition with Apache web server ! PHP script could be used to

1. Read the config file and capturing the parameters
2. Generate a HTML form (by pre-selecting the dropdown menus and radio buttons from the already read parameters)
3. And capturing the new edits and saving them to config file.

PHP script must be placed in /var/www/ directory of the embedded board. Then from any system, it could be accessed just by keying the IP address of the board and the script name using a simple web browser.